# whats wrong with this scrapy spider? scrapes only last url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

In method `parse()` spider crawls 4 urls and then sends to method `parse_dir_contents()` to scrape some data but only 4th url is being scraped I don't understand why it is not scraping other 3 urls?

```
import scrapy
from v_one.items import VOneItem
import json

class linkedin(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "linkedin"
    allowed_domains = ["linkedin.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "https://in.linkedin.com/directory/people-s-1-2-4/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        for href in response.xpath('//*[@id="seo-dir"]/div/div/div/ul/li/a/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())    
            print "________________"+url 
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)



    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="profile"]'):
            url = response.url
            print "____________"+url            
            item = VOneItem()
            item['name'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="name"]/text()').extract()
            item['headline'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="topcard"]/div/div/div/p/span/text()').extract()
            item['current'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="topcard"]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ol/li/span/text()').extract()
            item['education'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="topcard"]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ol/li/a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = url
            yield item
```

Comment: Your code visits every page/link already so I don't know how you think it is not scraping each url. Also your xpaths are very brittle, there are lots of class names to get the data more accurately. Also tbody is usually added by the browser so may not actually be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspecting the pages I think that there is no need of the `for` loop in the `parse_dir_contents` function. Make the function like this:

```
def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        item = VOneItem()
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="name"]/text()').extract()
        item['headline'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="topcard"]/div/div/div/p/span/text()').extract()
        item['current'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="topcard"]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ol/li/span/text()').extract()
        item['education'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="topcard"]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ol/li/a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = response.url
        return item
```

And check if this solves your issue.

Comment: is this approach misleading? Please don't down vote silently. Specify the reason.